# Function with a variable ExtJS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, extjs

At this time I want just to pass a value with a variable and show it in a modal window, this variable contains a link

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function mostrar_supports(link){
var link;
var win = new Ext.Window({
    title:  'Soporte Coprenal',
    width:  1000,
    height: 600,
    modal:  true,
    html:   "<iframe src="link" style='width:100%;height:100%;border:none;'></iframe>"
});

win.show();
return false;};
</script>
```

And the button is like that

```
             <%= link_to('#', 
                :onclick => "return mostrar_supports('#{request.host_with_port}/supports');") do %>
                <i class="wrenchicon-"></i>&nbsp;Soporte
            <% end %>
```

So I just want to show in the modal window the content of the url I pass, but I clicked it and doesn't happen anything, it's works just when I write manually the link, what could I do to fix it

```
html: '<iframe src="../supports" style="width:100%;height:100%;border:none;"></iframe>'
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this instead :

```
html:   "<iframe src='" + link + "' style='width:100%;height:100%;border:none;'></iframe>"
```

});